# querySelectorAll does not work after manipulating HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, rendering

it is a CRUD client list. i put the code inside a Main object for better control. all the selectors are inside a cacheSelectors function and there is another function for bindEvents, and the events are inside an object. I have a addButton and get the values from the inputs, then i throw each client into an array as a object. After that i use another function to display this array. Each client has a delete and edit button, after i manipulate the html to display the values on the table (i used a MAP function), the querySelectorAll stops working on the buttons.

i looked up and realized that after i manipulate the html (don't know if its called rendered) all the selectors were lost. After a mapped the clients i called the functions again (this.cacheSelectors() and this.bindEvents()) to re-get the elements, but as i do this way the list stops working and the new client always overwrites the last one. That is, the selectors work, but the list does not. I checked if the arrays was at least acumulating clients, but it always overwrites.

```
const Main = {
  init: function () {
    this.cacheSelectors()
    this.bindEvents()
    
    
  },

  cacheSelectors: function () {
    this.addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton')
    this.modal = document.querySelector('#modal')
    this.saveButton = document.querySelector('#saveButton')
    this.tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody')
    this.companyInput = document.querySelector('#companyName')
    this.contactInput = document.querySelector('#contactName')
    this.countryInput = document.querySelector('#countryName')
    this.inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
    this.removeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteButton')
    this.clients = []
  },



  bindEvents: function () {
    const self = this

    this.addButton.addEventListener('click', this.Events.addButton_click.bind(this))

    window.onclick = this.Events.closeModal_click

    this.saveButton.addEventListener('click', this.Events.saveClient_click.bind(this))

    this.removeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
      button.onclick = self.Events.removeButton_click
    })
  },


  Events: {
    addButton_click:function () {
      modal.style.display = 'block'
      this.inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.value = ''
      })
    },

    closeModal_click: function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    },

    saveClient_click: function () {
      const clientsScoped = this.clients
      
      
      companyName = this.companyInput.value
      contactName = this.contactInput.value
      countryName = this.countryInput.value

      const addClient = {
        id: (clientsScoped.length + 1),
        company: companyName,
        contact: contactName,
        country: countryName
      }

      if (companyName && contactName && countryName) {
        clientsScoped.push(addClient)
        modal.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        alert('All fields are required')
      }
      
      this.displayClients()
    
    },

    removeButton_click: function () {
      alert('test for echo')
    } 
  },

  displayClients: function () {
    clientsScoped = this.clients
    this.tbody.innerHTML = null
    

    clientsScoped.map((client) => {
      this.tbody.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
          <td>${client.id}</td>
          <td>${client.company}</td>
          <td>${client.contact}</td>
          <td>${client.country}</td>
          <td><div><i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i></div><div class="deleteButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></td></div>
        </tr>
      `
      this.cacheSelectors()
      this.bindEvents()
    }).join('')
    console.log(clientsScoped)
  },


}

Main.init()
```

Here is the repo if you wanna take a look at the code: https://github.com/matheusfribeiro/client-list-crud

Comment: The "id" attribute of an element must be a **unique** value on the page. Your code re-uses "editButton" as an id.

Comment: Where are you calling `document.querySelectorAll`?

Comment: in the cacheSelectors function

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to include that function (and all relevant functions, html, etc) in your post.